# Chromium apps doesn't follow system font settings in Manjaro KDE

Tags: kde, manjaro, fonts, gtk, fontconfig

I have changed my font settings for both qt and gtk but chromium based apps like chrome, vs code and slack seems to be not following font settings. Here is a screenshot of the problem I'm having. While I am using Inter UI, Chrome still has its default font. Is there anything I can do to change fonts in Chromium apps?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the set custom font setting in chromium I don't use vs code but I have to set the font from with in chromium to get it working on my system.

Comment: Can you help me where can I find that settings? I have tried to use customize font in Chrome or Chromium settings but it only changes website fonts.

Comment: Edited my answer to included manual option also if you prefer that way.

Comment: Edited again to add gsettings options also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package available in the standard repos called `kde-gtk-config` it supports both gtk2 and gtk3 install that package then after installation you will find under System Settings > Application Style > GNOME/GTK Application Style
font setting.  For gtk font setting to work you have to have both gtk2 and gtk3 set depending on which the application uses.

This is a link to the arch wiki on gtk it explains most everything.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK

If you would like to do it the manual way and edit the gtk rc files that is also explain with examples on the arch website.

EDIT: You can also use the gsettings command in the terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Monospace 11'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Sans 11'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 11'
```

EDIT: If you have issues with scaling see the font section in the below link it explains part of the reason why and a work around.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium#Fonts